# Dreamweaver CS5 management

Tags: ftp, dreamweaver, adobe-cs5

In Dreamweaver CS4, when you click to create a new website, you get a popup where you can choose to create a site with FTP only.

However, in Dreamweaver CS5, such popup doesn't exist and I am required to specify a local folder to store the files. And every time I save a edited HTML file, I had to "PUT" the file before it can be updated on the FTP server (how stupid this is).

Is there anyway that I can create a FTP only site in CS5?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but you can set it to automatically upload when saving a file.
Comment if you are still interested and I will tell you how.